# Error when converting time to another format in PHP

Tags: php, html, datetime, time, time-format

I'm trying to change the time format here.

In the database, the time are saved as '0','1200','1300','1400','900', etc.

I want them to have a normal format like this: '0:00 AM', '12:00 PM', '1:00 PM', '2:00 PM', '9:00 AM'.

In the code I'm using :

```
$timeFormated = DateTime::createFromFormat('Gi', $myTime[$i]);
$newDateString = $timeFormated->format('g:i A');
```

However, I'm getting the error saying “Call to a member function format() on a non-object”.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Before asking questions, wouldnt it be appropriate to do `var_dump($timeFormated, $myTime[$i], $newDateString)` first?

Comment: @Xorifelse Hey, thanks for the input. I'm fairly new to php. Could you be more specific? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Just copy that code after your 2 lines of code and see the results.

Comment: @Xorifelse It's giving me the same error after adding the code you provided.

Comment: Correct, we haven't changed anything now did we? It's called debugging, checking to see if every variable has the _assumed_ value. So by adding that line of code, you *must* see other data as well.

Comment: In fact, your code works peachy here, so the value of `$myTime[$i]` is incorrect because *that* is for us, the current *unknown* value.

Comment: I can still print out the value of $myTime[$i], and they are exactly the same thing as from the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132580/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-woshinibaba).

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you ensure your times are 4 digits.

You can do this by using:

```
$myTime = sprintf('%04d', $myTime);
```

So,

```
$timeFormated = DateTime::createFromFormat('Gi', '0'); // FALSE - doesn't work
$timeFormated = DateTime::createFromFormat('Gi', '0000'); // Works..!
```